# How do I create a file that corresponds to the minute of the day?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

```
suffix=$(date +%w)
touch ./$suffix.dat
```

That does it by the day of the week.  How do I do it by the minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the minute of the day (if I understood correctly you mean how many minutes are past since midnight), use this command:

```
$ echo "($(date +%k)*60)+$(date +%M)" | bc
503
```

- `date +%k` is the number of hours past
- `date +%M` the number of minutes
- a calculation is formed like this: `( 8*60)+23`
- and pipe to [`bc`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/bc/) that calcutales it

Comment: Ah, damn you, beat me by 30 seconds! :=)

Answer (score 1):

You run `man date` to get a full list of all the format codes.  This will tell you quite clearly how to print the minute instead of the weekday.

In case your system doesn't have man pages installed, see here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date

Comment: +1, don't know why people can't do one minute of research before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

hour=$(date +%H)
mins=$(date +%M)

mins_of_day=$(echo "60 * $hour + $mins"|bc)
touch $mins_of_day.dat
```